# How can I keep templates out of /js/?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS 2 along with backbone and pals to build the website. The beginning of every view is usually something like this:

```
define([
    'libs/jquery',
    'libs/underscore',
    'libs/backbone',
    'text!templates/coletas/agendamento.html',
], function(...
```

My problem is that the last line expects to find the template at `js/templates/coletas/agendamento.html`, and so this poor programmer ends up having to put non-js files in `/js/`. Is there a way to avoid that and set the base url to `./templates/` everytime I use the text plugin?

I also cannot use absolute paths, because I know not where my code will end up in the server.

Comment: Are you sure you're using require.js correctly? Your syntax looks correct, but you shouldn't have to explicitly define where jquery, underscore, etc. are. For example, the headers of my files like so: define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'models/overview',
  'text!templates/overview/main.html'
  ], 

and my libs are also stored in js/lib

Comment: Could you please submit some exampels at paste.se or anywhere, CamelBlues?

Comment: @knor I just figured out how my app was structured (lol). See my answer for how I define the templates directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet is from my main.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    loader: 'libs/backbone/loader',
    jQuery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    Underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
    templates: '../templates'
  }

});
```

Here is an example require.config that you can use to load in modules like my comment (sorry, I did not realize I had this in my app until I read your comment).

Once configured, then you can access various javascript libraries and your seperate templates directory like so (this snippet is from my js/views/overview/main.js:

```
define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'models/overview',
  'text!templates/overview/main.html'
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure I try to follow with `requirejs` is

```
webapp/
  main.js
  index.html
  app.js
  js/ <- your code here
  libs/ <- 3rd party stuff here
  templates/
  styles/
  etc/
  ...
```

so that the require.js -modules' dependencies are evaluated at the `webapp` - folder level, allowing you to maintain separation of different kinds of files.

Hope this helps!